# Problem in the solution of the simultaneous Ordinary Differential Equation

Tags: differential-equations

When i am running the following command

```
S = DSolve[{b1'[z] - 1 I*beta1*b1[z] - C*b2[z] == 0, 
   b2'[z] - 1 I*beta2*b2[z] + C*b1[z] == 0, 
   b1[1.581825567*10^-6] == 1.0030, 
   b2[1.581825567*10^-6] == 0.48581}, {b1, b2}, z]
```

I am getting the values of b1[z] and b2[z]. but my main problem is that whatever the values of b1[z] and b2[z], i am getting after solving the above equation, the sum of there values i.e.|b1|^2+|b2|^2 should be less then or equal to 1. i.e. |b1|^2+|b2|^2 <= 1; so please can anyone suggest me that how i will run the above equation with this condition |b1|^2+|b1|^2 <=1. i am trying to run my progarmme but it is showing some error whose snapshot i am attaching with this problem so please suggest me the right answer for the same problem[image]m.

Comment: In your picture you have three equations (2 DE, 1 algebraic) and 2 initial conditions.  That's three equation and two unknown.  But to clarify, you actually are aware of that and would like help enforcing the constraint ` |b1|^2+|b2|^2 <= 1`, right? (You tried the constraint as an equation in the image, instead of an inequality, yes?)

Comment: Did you notice that your initial conditions violate your constraint?

Comment: Note that `C` is a system symbol.  You should avoid it (as well as several other single capital letters).

Answer (score 2):

Did you notice that in In[22], `b1` is colored black and `b2` is colored blue? That means that b1 has a previously defined value and is not a dependent variable. So you have two equations with only one unknown, which is what the error message is telling you. This sort of thing happens when code gets evaluated more than once without clearing variables that have received assignments in previous evaluations.

Solutions are:

1. Kill and restart the evaluation kernel
2. Quit *Mathematica* and start a new session
3. Clear any assigned values from variables that might be causing trouble

Any one of these solutions should work.

Another piece of advice: in the future pay attention to way the code editor colors variables.